# Azure devops publish test results with links to requirement

Tags: azure-devops, ctest

I'm currently using cTest to publish test results from google test into azure.

Is there any way i can decorate my test so it comes up already linked to a requirement. without manually having to link it in azure?

Edit:
I'm using gtest recordproperty to add data to the xml output of the test case. I have tried with #1234( as in a commit), 1234 and several combinations. I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you could refer to this doc: [Run automated tests from test plans](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Ftest%2Frun-automated-tests-from-test-hub%3Fview%3Dazure-devops&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C0b148c1bfce244e393e408d8c0f635e5%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637471510988823394%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=%2FGi4BLxBmowAf6qqAKrZTKdTmf0Cv7xokWrGOEgl28c%3D&reserved=0) to automate test cases in your test plans and run them directly from Azure Test Plans. And then open the **Test Plans** page and select the test plan to see the status of your tests if tests are updated after test execution is complete.

In addition, if you turn on below “**Automatically link new work in this build**” option in build pipeline page, and then you can [link work item to Git commit](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fqueries%2Flink-work-items-support-traceability%3Fview%3Dazure-devops%26tabs%3Dnew-web-form%23work-items-linked-to-git-code-development&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C0b148c1bfce244e393e408d8c0f635e5%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637471510988823394%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=wG6JaD2rfB%2FltMrm8XbIqLeDF%2BCshw8dXCPYyK6Tyko%3D&reserved=0), the new build queued by this commit will link to this work item when it completes successfully.
[image]

Also, you could enable “**Create work item on failure**” option to create a new work item when this build is failed.

BTW, you could link work items to deployments refer to this [doc](https://nam06.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fboards%2Fwork-items%2Fwork-item-deployments-control%3Fview%3Dazure-devops&data=04%7C01%7Cv-edha%40microsoft.com%7C0b148c1bfce244e393e408d8c0f635e5%7C72f988bf86f141af91ab2d7cd011db47%7C1%7C0%7C637471510988833397%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C1000&sdata=Qy3Oh6zOhBLeKvZClL5zsml1%2FXzd6nbAVslc57%2Fmcps%3D&reserved=0).

Comment: @schultz If my answer helps,  you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues, thanks.